# Wix: Schedule a custom action to run after next reboot

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

Is it possible to schedule a custom action after a reboot?  Here's my predicament.

I have a product to uninstall and reinstall but some of the files are in use by another application at the time of reinstall.  This causes problems for the uninstall because the files are in use so I use a custom action which runs a batch file to rename the files in use.  This is a bit of a hack but makes the uninstall and reinstall not complain about the files being in use and replaces the files I want.

The reason for doing this is that I'm not allowed to force a reboot on the machine during the installation process but I need to make sure that the files get replaced.  So far so good.

This has the side effect of a bunch of files hanging around that I've renamed with a prefix toDelete_fileX.dll along with the new fileX.dll in the folder.

I have another custom action to delete these files which works fine but I can't run it at the end of the installation because the other application still has a handle to these renamed "toDelete_" prefixed files.

At some point in the future the system will be rebooted and this is where I would like the custom action to run to delete the "toDelete_" prefixed files.

Thanks. Neil

Comment: Why not stop the process which is using the files? It's much cleaner than renaming files and deleting them.

Comment: I'd love to but it's a strict requirement that the second application can't be stopped.  The idea is that the application that I'm working can be updated in the background but the main application will have scheduled reboots.  You're right though it's really nasty but as yet I've not found another solution.

Comment: Can you please include more details in your post? Perhaps an example scenario with the action you want. It's hard to understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a batch file that will search the directories for files prefixed with "toDelete_" and delete them.  I want this batch file to run when the computer is next rebooted.  I believe it's possible to schedule a custom action to run after the computer is rebooted and this custom action can run the batch file.  I just don't know how to write it in wxs.  I've seen it mentioned elsewhere online but I've not been able to find the example syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule actions after a reboot by using RunOnce registry key:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(VS.85).aspx?ppud=4
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137367

However, I think your going the wrong way with this. If you can offer more details about what you need to do (the design or concept), perhaps I can suggest a better alternative.

Comment: That looks like it'll do the job.  Thanks.

Comment: With regards to your concerns I need the msi to reinstall/uninstall silently and not force a reboot.  When reinstalling I'd like it to uninstall but leave the created content then reinstall.  The manual uninstall should delete all local content down to and including the root folder of the application.  All scenarios must be silent and not force a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this property [MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370377%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can use this to prevent the files in use dialog, combining this with /qn for msiexec will allow you to do it silently.

When it comes to installers, if you start running batch files during the install transaction you are really on your own as Windows Installer cannot track this.  Unless there's a really good reason to roll your own CA I would steer clear.

I think in your case Windows Installer will be able to take care of the renames, when you do eventually reboot.  If I've understood correctly you don't mind the reboot, its just you would like to schedule this at a later date/time.

Comment: I agree that I'm going about this the wrong way, I think i'll need to go back to the drawing board.  The wxs script i've inherited is quite a mess and has several components with lots of files which i've found makes reinstalling not behave properly.  Once this deadline passes I think I'll start the thing again.  Thanks again for the help.